# Recover windows 7 boot loader

Tags: linux, windows

After installing OpenSuse both the bootloader MBR and Grub2 are corrupted as during installation some errors where there while installing OpensSuse regarding Grub2. Currently my screen is showing error no kernel found. So how to get back the windows bootloader and my system to previous working state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Option 1

You need to boot a linux live cd and use ms-sys utility to recover the Windows boot loader. Look at [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Master_Boot_Record#Restoring_a_Windows_boot_record) for more information.

### Option 2

You can also boot a windows CD and do a startup repair. Take a look at [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/668-system-recovery-options.html), option 2.